# Concurrent add on non threadsafe HashSet - what is the worst that could happen?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, hashset

**Situation:**

Multiple Threads are only adding values to a non threadsafe `java.util.HashSet` and no other operation is done on the `Set` until these threads have been stopped.

**Question:**

What is the worst that could happen?

Comment: "What is the worst that could happen?" - Explosion of the sun.

Comment: concurrency problem can cause any problem in the world. Explosion of the sun is nothing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on what you consider as being "worst".

I'm not sure whether this question aimed at a detailed, technical analysis of the current implementation considering all possible race conditions and the nitty-gritty details of the Java memory model.

So if the question is: "What can *provably* happen in the current implementation?" then I have to say: "I don't know". And I assume that hardly anybody knows this for sure in detail. (It's somehow like asking "Which parts of your car will be broken after you hit a wall with 100 mph?" - well, maybe the steering wheel will still be intact, but does this matter?)

But if the question is "What is not unlikely to happen when accessing a not-threadsafe `HashMap` with multiple threads?" then there are many possible answers:

- Deadlocks
- Exceptions
- Missing elements
- Elements being inserted multiple times
- Elements being inserted into the wrong hash bin
- ...

(Roughly ordered by my subjective interpretation of "badness"...)

---

EDIT: A clarification for the comment: Of course, an element could only be added twice if the call to insert it occurs multiple times. According to the specifiction, the `HashMap` should contain each key at most *once*. But the call for adding a new entry to the `HashMap` eventually delegates to the call

```
void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
    size++;
}
```

And there is no (obvious) reason why no other thread should cause a rehash (and thus, the creation of a new `table` array) between the first and the second line of this method. Then the `bucketIndex` for this call would be wrong. When the entry is then added a second time, it could use the (then) *right* `bucketIndex`, and thus, would afterwards be contained *twice* in the map.

But again: In order to really *prove* that this might happen, one would have to study the implementation in a detail that is hardly feasible. The bottom line is: Basically *anything* can go wrong when adding elements with multiple threads to a non-threadsafe `HashMap`.

Comment: It is possible that an element could be inserted multiple times or with a wrong hash? Do you know how?

Comment: @mklemenz Added an EDIT (and a disclaimer)

Comment: @Marco13, could you please explain how it is possible to have a case of "Missing elements"?

Comment: @IgweKalu Again, it's hard to prove, but the scenario could be similar to the one described in the "edit": Existing elements might be overwritten by new ones (even if the new ones have a different hash code and are not `equals` to the existing ones), when two `createEntry` calls interfere.

Answer (score 3):

The worst that can happen (besides an erroneous state of course) is probably an infinite loop when adding a value, blocking one of your threads.

See [Paul Tyma article](http://mailinator.blogspot.fr/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html) for more information on this case.

Comment: Well I learned something new today, thanks for the link to Pauls post

Answer (score 3):

What I have seen happen is you can get a corrupted linked list in your underlying HashMap (for handling collisions) which points back to itself.  This is an issue I have seen a number of times over the years and it results in the thread going into an infinite loop.