# Mutate Non thread safe collections

Tags: java, thread-safety

Can anyone please explain to me the consequences of mutating a collection in java that is not thread-safe and is being used by multiple threads?

Comment: Consequence: The internal structure of the Collection may be corrupted.

Comment: [Nasal demons.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)  That is, demons may fly out of your nose.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632552/concurrent-add-on-non-threadsafe-hashset-what-is-the-worst-that-could-happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are undefined and somewhat random.

With JDK collections that are designed to fail fast, you might receive a ConcurrentModificationException.  This is really the only consequence that is specific to thread safety with collections, as opposed to any other class.

Problems that occur generally with thread-unsafe classes may occur:

- The internal state of the collection might be corrupted.
- The mutation may appear to be successful, but the changes may not, in fact, be visible to other threads at any given time.  They might be invisible at first and become visible later.
- The changes might actually be successful under light load, but fail randomly under heavy load with lots of threads in contention.
- Race conditions might occur, as was mentioned in a comment above.

There are lots of other possibilities, none of them pleasant.  Worst of all, these things tend to most commonly reveal themselves in production, when the system is stressed.

In short, you probably don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The invariants of the data structure will not be guaranteed.

For example:
If thread 2 does a read whilst thread 1 is adding to the DS thread 1 may consider this element added while thread 2 doesn't see that the element has been added yet.

There are plenty of data structures that aren't thread-safe that will still appear to function(i.e. not throw) in a multi threaded environment and they might even perform correctly under certain circumstances(like if you aren't doing any writes to the data structure).

To fully understand this topic exploring the different classes of bugs that occur in concurrent systems is recommended: this short document seems like a good start.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-bugs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The most common outcome is it looks like it works, but doesn't work all the time.

This can mean you have a problem which

- works on one machine but doesn't on another.
- works for a while but something apparently unrelated changes and your program breaks.
- whenever you have a bug you don't know if it's a multi-threading issue or not if you are not using thread safe data structures.

What can happen is;

- you rarely/randomly get an error and strange behaviour
- your code goes into an infinite loop and stops working (HashMap used to do this)

The only option is to;

- limit the amount of state which is shared between threads, ideally none at all.
- be very careful about how data is updated.
- don't rely on unit tests, you have to understand what the code doing and be confident it will be behave correctly in all possible situations.